# SQL Server CE: the file resolves to a path that is too long. 

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, ef-code-first

I'm trying to track down a SQL Server CE issue that means I cannot use SQL Server CE on a local hard drive of my computer. Clearly the error message is a bogus one as the filename is nowhere near 260 chars

> The file resolves to a path that is too long.
>   The maximum length is 260 characters. [ File name = D:\db.sdf ]

Specifically the D: drive. I have a very simple EF code first app that I want to unit test using SQL Server Compact Edition. When I run the app the first time I try to access the database I get the error above. Originally I tried using a simple filename as the Data Source in the connection string:

```
<add name="MyContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=db.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

but got the error.

Then I tried specifying the root drive:

```
<add name="MyContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=D:\db.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

and got the same error

If I tried using either a network drive or the c drive:

```
<add name="MyContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=C:\db.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

or

```
<add name="MyContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=\\Server\path\db.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

The it worked fine and the db was created and the operations performed.

I tried digging around in procmon and all I could find was an Explorer.exe process reporting invalid device for the d: drive.

Any help greatly appreciated

Cheers

Dave

Comment: UPDATE: I was trying to create a visual studio 2010 database project on my D: drive and got exactly the same error message - I tried to create on the C: drive and it worked fine. This seems to be either an issue with my machine configuration (although I can replicate the problem on another machine so unlikely or a bug in the SqlServerCE implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit similar to my problem

I'm using MS Sql Server Management Studio Express R2 SP1...

When I try to create a CE/sdf database on the D:drive it just blinks at me, and asks me for the db path again

I managed to create a CE db on D: via Visual Studio (the inline server manager), but SSMSE still can't access it

If I do it on the C: it works fine.

Bizarre, but I think Sql CE just hates none C drives?